# Frameset indeed in frame problem PYTHON SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, frame

I want to go inside frame name "body", but it isnt work. I can go to first frame and everything works, but problem is when I try to go inside indeed frameset. Selenium cant see it

This is my code:

```
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/frameset/frame[2]")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
frame= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/frameset/frame[1]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

HTML CODE:

```
<html><head>
      <title>
         Le Moniteur belge.
      </title> 
</head>
    <frameset rows="14%,*">
    <frame src="rech_f1.htm" name="frame1_fr" noresize="">
    <frame src="rech_f2.htm" name="frame2_fr" cd_frame_id_="f1e39289d55588245ed84ea909665732">
    <html>
    <frameset>
     <frame src="list_body.pl?language=fr&amp;sql=htit+contains++'roche'&amp;fromtab=+moftxt+UNION+montxt+UNION+modtxt&amp;rech=83&amp;trier=promulgation&amp;tri=dd+AS+RANK+&amp;dt=&amp;ddda=&amp;dddm=&amp;dddj=&amp;ddfa=&amp;ddfm=&amp;ddfj=&amp;pdda=&amp;pddm=&amp;pddj=&amp;pdfa=&amp;pdfm=&amp;pdfj=&amp;numac=&amp;bron=&amp;htit=roche&amp;text1=&amp;choix1=ET&amp;text2=&amp;choix2=ET&amp;text3=&amp;exp=&amp;&amp;fr=f&amp;nl=n&amp;du=d&amp;an=" name="Body" scrolling="auto">
        </frameset>
       </html>

    <noframes>
    pas de frames
    </noframes>
    </frameset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the frame `body` is in the second frameset which is inside the first frameset. So you can find it using full xpath: `(By.XPATH, "/html/frameset/frameset/frame")`
Or you can try to find it using this realtive XPATH `(By.XPATH, "//frame[@name='Body']")]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate elements correctly. Also, according to HTML you shared the 'body' frame is not inside `frame2_fr`. In case all you want is to go inside `body` frame you can do that with the following code:

```py
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//frame[@name='Body']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

When you finished, don't forget to get out to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this frame is indeed. Im sure

Comment: OK, I see. The second frame is not inside the first. So, second frame is with name Body. What is the first name, what unique attribute it has?

Comment: Site has two main Frame. First is frame1_fr and second frame2_fr. I go to inside frame2_fr. Inside this frame are two another frame "body" and "foot". I want go inside the body. First I go to inside frame2_fr and after that I try go to the body but Selenium doesnt see this frame.

Comment: OK, I see. Again, that frame is not inside other frame. See my updated answer